# Navigation Error when navigating to Home page from Firebase registration

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-native-firebase-tutorial/ in attempt to learn how to use firebase, and even though I've followed the code very closely, I'm receiving a NAVIGATION error:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":{"user":{"id":"AWSKEmmUsua5koR1V3x5bapc3Eq2","email":"tk@gmail.com","fullName":"t"}}} was not handled by any navigator.

> Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

I do however, have a screen named Home. App.js:

```
import Home from './src/Home';
import Login from './src/Login/Login';
import Registration from './src/Registration/Registration';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    { user ? (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home"> 
        {props => <Home {...props} extraData={user} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    ) : (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={Registration} />
      </>
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

When I use the Registration form to register a new user and Navigate to the Home page is when I get the error. Registration.js:

```
import { firebase } from '../firebase/config';

export default function Registration({ navigation }) {
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
}

const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match!");
        return
    }
    // This works. However, navigation does not for some reason
    firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            const uid = response.user.uid
            const data = {
                id: uid,
                email,
                fullName
            }
            const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
            usersRef.doc(uid).set(data).then(() => {
                // This is where the navigation error lies. It has nothing to do with the component
                // This error happened even when I created a new plain Home component
                navigation.navigate("Home", { user: data})
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error))
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
}

return (
....Input Forms
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.loginButton}
                onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create Account</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I have used React Navigation before and haven't run into this issue. I am not using nested navigators and cannot see where the issue lies. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Göksel Pırnal answers:

At first, suppose there is no user. So We are in *Registration Screen*. At that stage, our navigator doesn’t even know whether there is any *“Home”* Screen. At this stage, our navigator only knows 2 screens: *“Login”* and *“Registration”* screens.

You need to notify our app.js whether anyone registered in the *Registration screen* or not. After that our app.js should change the value of 'user' in [user,setUser].

In your, *App.js* put this lines of code:

```
const [initializing,setInitializing]=useState(true)
useEffect(()=>{
    const subscriber=firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{  
      setUser(user)
      setInitializing(false)
    })
    return subscriber
  },[])

if (initializing) return null  //Here you may use an Activity indicator
```

Then after rerendering our navigator will see the value of “user” has changed and it should navigate to the *Home screen*.

And guess what! You do not need to navigate manually from Registration Screen as you already put a condition in App.js ( in return () ).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem where you check the `user` value in `App.js`. After the registration is done, you did not assign the state in the `App.js` page and it will always be `null`. The `Home` page will not be added to the stack because the `user` value is `null`. That's why you got the error.

Solution: You need to notify `App.js` after registration.